# Relaunch a program when error detected

Tags: java, exception

I am currently making a simple program about reading a file. I have a try and catch block showed as below. What I want to do is if the program detected error (exception), it will relaunch the entire program 3 times. After that, if the error still occur, the program terminated by itself and then print out the exception message. I got the file part working, but now I have no idea how to do the relaunch part. Help will be appreciated, thanks

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;



 public class Test {

        public static void main(String args[]){

             try {
                    // constructor may throw FileNotFoundException
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader("someFile.txt");
                    int i=0;
                    while(i != -1){
                        //reader.read() may throw IOException
                        i = reader.read();
                        System.out.println((char) i );
                    }


                    reader.close();
                    System.out.println("--- File End ---");
                }

                //Relaunch program
                    retry();

                 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    //do something clever with the exception
                    System.out.println("File not found");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //do something clever with the exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        private static void retry() {


        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you just put the code in `main` in a while loop? If exception, loop 3 times (you can keep track by having a counter), otherwise break the loop.

Comment: Well. What you should do is move your main logic out of main. Then the solution might become more clear. Break down the problem into parts.

Comment: I have updated my code, see if this is what you mean

Comment: Just a general remark, please try to use Java naming conventions and write class names with a capital letter at the front like: Test

Comment: Hi Leonid, Thanks for your correction, will remember it next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following way,

```
public class Test {//Start class name with capital case

     public static void main(String args[]){
          int counter = 1;
          while(counter <= 3) {//try until counter reaches 3
              boolean isSuccess = readFile(counter++);
              if(isSuccess) {
                  break;
              }
          }
     }

     private static boolean readFile(int attempt) {
          try {
             //read file here
             return true;          
           } catch(Exception e) {
             if(attempt == 3) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return false;
          } 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I get what you are trying to do there. Is there another way to do this? What if I want if I want to keep the structure of my code as I showed above? Because this is just a demo ( I want to keep it simple) and I want to try it in other program that I have created on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
private static int attempts = 1;
synchronized private static void retry() {
    if(attempts == 3)
        return;

    new Thread() {
        main(null);
    }.start();

    attempts++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I have tried your code. It said Syntax error on token "null", delete this

Comment: No, it's not a syntax error, it's required in place of the `args` array. See my recent edit, where I added control to stop after 3 attempts.